# Java Websocket won't open properly WAS 9.0

Tags: javascript, java, angular, websocket, websphere

I've created a pretty straight forward Java websocket and I'm trying to put it to the test in our test environment. On my local machine, the websocket opens seamlessly, stays with the readystate code '1' and all seems to work well.

On my test machine however, even though the socket appears to open, I still check the readystate and it gives the code '1', the upgrade from Https to websocket happens in the network tab, the OnOpen function in my Java code doesn't seem to get triggered ( I'm trying to log the userId that's coming with the new connection on socket open and that doesn't show either in my test environment logs. On my local machine, that works as well)

```
private static final ArrayList<Session> connectedSessions = new ArrayList<>();

@OnClose
public void closeSession(Session session) {
    try {
        connectedSessions.remove(session);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message, final Session session) {
    broadcastMessage(message, session);
}

@OnOpen
public void openSession(@PathParam("userId") String userId, Session session) {
    try {
        session.getUserProperties().put("USER_ID", userId);
        connectedSessions.add(session);
        LOGGER.info("-------- Connection id ---------" + userId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

On the front end I'm using angular, but no other websocket framework, just plain javascript, and for my backend I'm running Xframe 2.2 with Websphere application server 9.0. I'm sure I'm calling the right endpoint since it works on my local machine and I've tested it multiple times with multiple sessions.

EDIT: adding the angular code below

```
this.ws= new WebSocket("wss://" + env.websocketUrl + "socket" + this.context.settings.userId);
this.ws.onmessage = (event) => {
      this.update(event.data, this.context.settings.userId);
    };

 doSomething(data) {
        this.ws.send(data);
}
```

The thing to note is that the message gets sent. I checked the frames of the WS, but I get no response. It stays "pending"

Comment: Since it works locally, but not on another machine, I'd investigate whether it's a CORS issue. If you post the relevant Angular code, along with the URLs that it uses to talk to the server websocket, someone here might be able to help.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek edited the code with the angular call

Comment: What I'm interested in is the actual URL for the Angular app vs. the actual URL for the websocket, to see if there could be a CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can be closed. Turns out my company is blocking any http2 calls that runs on our test/prod servers. It's why websockets were working on my local machine.